# Use a local file path for file reader

Tags: javascript, filereader

I have a javascript that reads a file, but I don't want to ask the user to select a file. I want the file to be loaded on `window.onload`

```
function handleFiles(files) {
   if (window.FileReader) {
        getAsText(files[0]);
    } else {
        alert('FileReader are not supported in this browser.');
    }
}
function getAsText(fileToRead) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = loadHandler;
    reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
}

function processData(event) {
    var csv = event.target.result;
    var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var lines = [];
    while (allTextLines.length) {
        lines.push(allTextLines.shift().split(','));
    }
    console.log(lines);
}
```

Comment: Browsers don't allow that due to security concerns

Answer (score 0):

> I have a javascript that reads a file, but I don't want to ask the user to select a file.

You simply cannot do that. It would be a massive privacy problem. You **have** to get the file from the user.

Comment: @Jerika: It makes no difference whatsoever. You don't have text files on your system that you don't want random people hosting websites to be able to get and read? If you use a \*nix-based system (Linux, Mac OS, etc.) that would the list of users defined for the system, just about every settings file you have, ... But it's just as true for Windows and other OS's; people have text files that they don't want other people reading.